# Can I distribute Maven archetype in eclipse plugin without manual artefact installation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, archetypes

I have custom Maven archetype which is installed in my local Maven repository. Additionally I have eclipse plugins contributing a "New Project" wizard generating a project from the archetype (using m2eclipse).

The problem is how to distribute the archetype to other people. 
I can ask them to install it manually with mvn install:install-file for example, but that's a manual step and don't want this.
Ideally I want to put it inside the eclipse plugins I provide and call it from there. Is this possible?

Thank You!

Comment: This might help:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089419/install-maven-archetype)

Comment: Thank you, c_sharp, but I am looking for a way without manual installation.