# Maven archetype:generate

Tags: maven, archetypes

I am trying to generate a project as instructed by a third party. However, for an unknown reason it is not working. Given my limited knowledge, I will be grateful is someone can point me in the right direction to solve this issue.

I did a

```
mvn archetype:crawl
```

then I am trying to create my project in interactive mode as follow:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

I am presented with the only available choice. Here is the complete dialog:

```
C:\Projets\OO_Actions\LoadFile>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: local -> com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-plugin-archetype (sample-project)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-plugin-archetype
Choose archetype:
1: local -> com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-plugin-archetype (sample-project)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47.835 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-13T17:00:09-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-plugin-archetype:10.70.00) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I wonder why I receive a message saying the archetype doesn't exist while it was actually presented as the only valid choice. What am I missing?

Comment: did you install it first? I think you need to do a `mvn install` first from the archetype project directory.

Comment: Its also wierd that you get to *Choose archetype..* twice. And did you try this from within a existing maven project? If so, what's the ouput on trying it outside of a maven project.

Comment: @nullpointer I ran this commands in a bare directory supposed to hold my new project.

Comment: @Karl Nicholas, what do you mean? Nowhere in the instructions I have this is mentioned. What is done, is unzipping a file from the third party into the %HOMEDIR%/.m2/repository directory, run the mvn archetype:crawl and then create the project in a bare directory.

Comment: *Its also wierd that you get to Choose archetype.. twice*?how about this?

Comment: @nullpointer, if you look carefully at the output, you will see I answered com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-plugin-archetype the first time instead of entering a number, which is what I did the second time. I don't believe it is something you should consider. If I rerun the command and just answer with the number the first time I will not be asked twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089419/install-maven-archetype You need to install to copy the files into your local repo which is what maven works from when it does the generate.

Comment: @Achille Ya got it. Looks strange, whats that default archetype anyway. Any idea?

Comment: @nullpointer, this is the third party archetype I need to use.

Comment: @Achille and you're sure its present in your .m2 folder? By some chance can you delete the artifact for this archetype and pull it fresh?

Comment: Look here too. http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/ It says you can do archetype:update-local-catalog for installation.

Comment: @nullpointer - what i'm trying to say is that is what the `install` does - it updates the local repo, or .m2 folder.

Comment: @KarlNicholas I agree but the artifact is already present, so install wouldn't download it to m2. Thats why asking to clean up and download.

Comment: @Karl Nicholas, I get it. First of all, the .m2 directory was already there since I am using Maven from within Eclipse's integration and it is working fine for my Eclipse projects. What happened, is I need to add some stuff to it from a third party. What I got from that third party is two zipped file I need to unzip in the .m2/repository, then run the mvn archetype:crawl command which is supposed to update the catalog.

Comment: @nullpointer, the archetype is not pulled from anywhere, it is dropped in the repository when I unzip the files provided by the third party.

Comment: In that case I believe we should close this as not reproducible @Achille . The method of manualy arhiving the artifact is also not a good practice either.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Yea, okay. I don't know then. Perhaps the third party stuff needs to be "installed" as well. Sorry can't shed more light on it.

Comment: @Karl Nicholas, may be, however I have no specific instructions in the third party manual.

Comment: @nullpointer, since I was new to Maven, I was thinking it may be something with my commands, usage, steps. So, yes I agree this problem is then not of interest for a large audience unless there is people here developing actions for HP OO.

Comment: Did you find this? https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Operations-Orchestration/Creating-a-sample-action-plugin-with-HPE-OO-10-70/td-p/800280/page/2

Comment: @Karl Nicholas, I will try a couple of things base on this. I did open a trouble ticket to HPE, now MicroFocus about this. Obviously the documentation is outdated. The HPE documentation sucks most of the time unless you are doing very standard stuff and never try to exploit the full capability of a product.

Comment: Even this thread on HPE's site is outdated. There isn't any files supposed to be in the maven repository for this to work. The entire oo subdirectory is missing.