# maven custom archetype publishing to repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have created a custom maven archetype. Now I want to push this to a private repository so that it can be used by other project members as well. At the same time I need this to be listed in eclipse/other IDE. Could you please advise how this can be achieved. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089419/install-maven-archetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pom file as a reference to build your jar file and distribute it to an internal repository.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>myJar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tbx.localrepository.ext>http://artifacts.project.net/artifactory/myProject</tbx.localrepository.ext>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>com.localrepository.ext</id>
            <name>Intranet Maven Repository for Extensions</name>
            <url>${com.localrepository.ext}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.localrepository.ext</id>
            <name>Intranet Maven Repository for Extensions</name>
            <url>${com.localrepository.ext}</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!--//add dependencies-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- Final jar name-->
        <finalName>myJar</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When someone needs to use the jar file it can be specified in the `pom.xml` file of that particular project with the same details as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>myJar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @vipin ev was't the above answer useful for your question?